# Splitting time series with Google BigQuery by field value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset in Google Bigquery with vehicle positions over time and the direction they are going relative to a base, like

```
time |  x  |  y  | direction | vehicle_id
-----|-----|-----|-----------|-----------
0:00 | ... | ... | returning |    100
0:00 | ... | ... | returning |    200
0:00 | ... | ... | exploring |    300
0:05 | ... | ... | returning |    100
0:05 | ... | ... | exploring |    200
0:05 | ... | ... | exploring |    300
0:10 | ... | ... | exploring |    100
0:10 | ... | ... | exploring |    200
0:10 | ... | ... | exploring |    300
0:15 | ... | ... | exploring |    100
0:15 | ... | ... | exploring |    200
0:15 | ... | ... | returning |    300
```

I'm able to aggregate by vehicle easily, but I can't come up with a query that can break each vehicle series into 'trips', consisting of sequential occurrences of 'returning' or 'exploring'. I have read about analytic functions but none seem to fit the bill.

```
SELECT
  vehicle_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(direction, time, x, y)
    ORDER BY time) as series
FROM t
GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

```
[
  {
    "vehicle_id": 100,
    "series":
    [
      {"direction": "returning", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "returning", "time": "0:05", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:10", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:15", "x": ..., "y": ...}
    ]
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 200,
    "series":
    [
      {"direction": "returning", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...}
    ]
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 300,
    "series":
    [
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "exploring", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...},
      {"direction": "returning", "time": "0:00", "x": ..., "y": ...}
    ]
  }
]
```

What I really want is to have a sequence of trips by vehicle, where each trip has a direction and a series of (t, x, y) positions. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and uses pure SQL to achieve the very same result

```
#standardSQL
SELECT vehicle_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(direction, trip)) trips
FROM (
  SELECT vehicle_id, direction, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(time, x, y) ORDER BY time) trip
  FROM dataset
  GROUP BY vehicle_id, direction
)
GROUP BY vehicle_id
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:00' AS time,
    0.1 AS x, 0.1 AS y, 'returning' AS direction,
    100 AS vehicle_id
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:00', 0.2, 0.2, 'returning', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:00', 0.3, 0.3, 'exploring', 300
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:05', 1.1, 1.1, 'returning', 100
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:05', 1.2, 1.2, 'exploring', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:05', 1.3, 1.3, 'exploring', 300
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:10', 2.1, 2.1, 'exploring', 100
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:10', 2.2, 2.2, 'exploring', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:10', 2.3, 2.3, 'exploring', 300
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:15', 3.1, 3.1, 'exploring', 100
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:15', 3.2, 3.2, 'exploring', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:15', 3.3, 3.3, 'returning', 300
)
SELECT vehicle_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(direction, trip)) trips
FROM (
  SELECT vehicle_id, direction, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(time, x, y) ORDER BY time) trip
  FROM dataset
  GROUP BY vehicle_id, direction
)
GROUP BY vehicle_id
```

result is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a wrong mental model for GROUP BY!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to come up with a pure SQL solution, but Bigquery does provide a way to execute arbitrary processing within itself in the form of user-defined functions (UDF).

By aggregating the entire series of a vehicle into an array, we can feed it into a Javascript function that performs the necessary logic and splits the series in a sequence of trips.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION split_trips(
    series ARRAY<STRUCT<direction STRING,
                        time TIMESTAMP,
                        x FLOAT64,
                        y FLOAT64>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<direction STRING,
                     trip ARRAY<STRUCT<time TIMESTAMP,
                                       x FLOAT64,
                                       y FLOAT64>>>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  if (series.length == 0) {
    return [];
  }
  let result = [];

  let trip = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < series.length-1; i++) {
    let {direction, time, x, y} = series[i];
    trip.push({time: time, x: x, y: y});
    if (direction == series[i+1].direction) {
      continue;
    }
    result.push({direction: direction, trip: trip});
    trip = [];
  }
  let lastEntry = series[series.length-1];
  trip.push({time: lastEntry.time, x: lastEntry.x, y: lastEntry.y});
  result.push({direction: lastEntry.direction, trip: trip});
  return result;
""";

WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:00' AS time,
    0.1 AS x, 0.1 AS y, 'returning' AS direction,
    100 AS vehicle_id
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:00', 0.2, 0.2, 'returning', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:00', 0.3, 0.3, 'exploring', 300
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:05', 1.1, 1.1, 'returning', 100
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:05', 1.2, 1.2, 'exploring', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:05', 1.3, 1.3, 'exploring', 300
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:10', 2.1, 2.1, 'exploring', 100
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:10', 2.2, 2.2, 'exploring', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:10', 2.3, 2.3, 'exploring', 300
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:15', 3.1, 3.1, 'exploring', 100
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:15', 3.2, 3.2, 'exploring', 200
  UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-07 00:00:15', 3.3, 3.3, 'returning', 300
),
by_vehicle AS (
SELECT
  vehicle_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(direction, time, x, y)
            ORDER BY TIME) AS series
FROM dataset
GROUP BY vehicle_id
)
SELECT
  vehicle_id,
  split_trips(series) AS trips
FROM by_vehicle
```

The [Bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits) notes that each function invocation can produce at most 5 MiB of data, so considering the timestamp (64 bits) and two floats (64 bits each) that gives us at most ~200K entries to manipulate at once for each vehicle.